# Why an intialized variable is causing function name must be a string error

Tags: php

error for intialize variable

```
$errors=array();

$errors =[];
```

If i intialize my variable errors to `array()` it gives the error, if with `[]` there is no error can someone explain why?

Comment: what error do you get? `$errors=array();` has  been valid syntax for a very long time

Comment: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Comment: you must have some other code https://3v4l.org/pPgUL

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write something like `$errors = $array()`? That would cause that error.

Comment: this is what it evaluated to

Comment: Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(includes/config.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/tmp:/in:/etc) in /in/OVnc7 on line 2 Warning: include(includes/config.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /in/OVnc7 on line 2 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /in/OVnc7 on line 2

Comment: evaluation gives same with either errors=[], errors=array()

Comment: thanks, so based on previous answer php doesn't know that array() is an array when it is assigned to variable? and no id did not $array()